# How can i apply Multiple In clause in a single MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have list of ids and corresponding creation dates
for Exmple :

> 1  2014-05-01
>
> 2  2014-07-01
>
> 3  2014-08-01

Need suggestion regarding writing a `MySQL` select statement which gives id details after corresponding creation date.

```
select id,count(*) from id_details where id IN(1,2,3) where resolved_at >(2014-05-01,2014-07-01,2014-08-01) group by id
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear

Comment: requirement is find count of all rows where id=1 and created_at after ids creation date.trying to do it IN CLAUSE for multiple ids

Comment: And I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: {select count(*) from a where (id = 1 and resolved_at = '2014-05-01') OR (id = 2 and resolved_at = '2014-05-01'}..like this using IN query for multiple ids

Comment: @jacob53 do you mean to see where the creation date and the resolved date are the same?

Answer (score 0):

The date condition for `resolved_at` column is not correct. Again, if you have two `WHERE` clause in your query, that as well not correct. You can's specify `>` condition in `IN` clause like you are trying. Your query should look like

```
select id,count(*) 
from id_details 
where id IN (1,2,3) 
and (resolved_at >= '2014-05-01' 
and resolved_at <= '2014-08-01') 
group by id
```

I think you are just trying to use `IN` operator for `resolved_at` column like

```
select id, 
count(*) 
from id_details 
where id IN (1,2,3) 
and resolved_at IN ('2014-05-01','2014-07-01','2014-08-01') 
group by id
```

Comment: each id has its own creation date.1 should mapped to '2014-05-01' not with all dates

Comment: Then just us `IN` clause without specifying any conditional operator. See edited answer.

Comment: Try the below query. It should work as expected. Did you tried? You are thinking of a condition like `where (id = 1 and resolved_at = '2014-05-01') OR (id = 2 and ....`. second query does the same thing.

Comment: @jacob53, did you tried the second query; it should get you the expected result. Consider, accepting the answer if it's helpful.